# An stronger form of the existence of a smooth Urysohn function on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds, global-analysis

I proved the following form of the existence of a smooth Urysohn function::

**proposition**: For any compact set $K\subset\mathbb R^n$ and any open set $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ where $K\subset U$, there is a smooth($C^{\infty}$) function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f_{|_{K}}\equiv1$ and $\ \text{supp}(f)\subset U$.

For the its proof I used compactivity of $K$ strictly for defining $f$ .

Now, I wish to show that if $K$ be only a  closed set then the above proposition still hold in the following form:

**The problem**: For any closed set $C\subset\mathbb R^n$ and any open set $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ where $C\subset U$, there is a smooth($C^{\infty}$) non negative function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $f_{|_{C}}>0$ and $\text{supp}(f)\subset U$.

How?

Comment: Partition of unity plus the compact case.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer:I don't want to use partition of unity. I want to show it directly like to the first  proposition.

Comment: Why don't you want to use partitions of unity?

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer:  Because of that in the book am reading,   the problem is introdused befor than partition of unity.

Answer (score 2):

Since we don't require that $f \equiv 1$ on $C$, we can get by without partitions of unity, although the construction takes us a few steps towards (smooth) partitions of unity.

For $k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, define

$$C_k := \{ x \in C : k-1 \leqslant \lVert x\rVert \leqslant k\}.$$

Then each $C_k$ is compact (maybe empty), and

$$C = \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty C_k.$$

Further define small open neighbourhoods

$$U_k := \bigl\{ x \in U : \operatorname{dist}(x,C_k) < \tfrac{1}{3}\bigr\}$$

of $C_k$.

Apply the proposition to all pairs $C_k \subset U_k$ to have a smooth $f_k \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,1]$ with $f_k \equiv 1$ on $C_k$ and $\operatorname{supp} f_k \subset U_k$.

Since $U_k \subset \bigl\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : k-\frac{4}{3} < \lVert x\rVert < k + \frac{1}{3}\bigr\}$, every ball with radius $\leqslant \frac{1}{6}$ meets at most two of the $U_k$, hence

$$f(x) := \sum_{k = 1}^\infty f_k(x)$$

converges locally uniformly, and since every point has a neighbourhood on which all but finitely many $f_k$ vanish identically, $f$ is smooth, and $\operatorname{supp} f \subset \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^\infty U_k \subset U$. And we have $f(x) \geqslant 1$ for $x\in C$.

Comment: 1. Why $C = \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty C_k$? 2. Why is convergent the series ?

Comment: 1. For every $x \in C$, we have $\lVert x\rVert \geqslant 0$. Let $k = \lfloor \lVert x\rVert\rfloor + 1$, then $x \in C_k$. 2. I would like that you find the answer yourself. How does $f_k$ behave on $C_m$ when $m \neq k$?

Comment: My idea is that all of $U_k:=U$.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Anyway $\bigcup U_k \subset U$, which is enough. The support of $f$ is contained in $\bigcup U_k$.

Comment: In fact, the family $\{ U_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\}$ has a property that makes questions of convergence a non-issue. Try to make a sketch to see what.

Comment: The number of componets $f$ may be infinite in some point of $U$.

Comment: In fact, no. For $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, the open ball $B_{1/6}(x)$ around $x$ with radius $\frac{1}{6}$ intersects at most two $U_k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please add a proof for that requiring $f\equiv 1$ on $C$? (Just like OP, I know how to prove compact-open version of $C^\infty$ Urysohn lemma, but don't know how to prove closed-open version) Since I do not know manifolds, I have a trouble understanding proofs for this on webs. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @DanielFischer Here is a post I asked for this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1784755/44669

Comment: @Rubertos Are you familiar (at least somewhat) with partitions of unity?

Comment: @DanielFischer I studied parititions of unity and paracompact spaces given in the text Munkres-Topology, but that is it. (Like, existence of **continuous** partition of unity. Nothing about differentiable partition of unity..) Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: @Rubertos I think that should suffice (for the $\mathbb{R}^n$ part). So you have disjoint closed $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. For every $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ choose an open ball $W_x$ around $x$ such that $W_x \cap B = \varnothing$ if $x \in A$, $W_x \cap A = \varnothing$ if $x \in B$, and $W_x \cap (A\cup B) = \varnothing$ if $x \notin (A\cup B)$. Let $\{Z_{\iota} : \iota \in I\}$ be a locally finite refinement of $\{ W_x : x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, and $\{\varphi_{\iota} : \iota \in I\}$ a smooth partition of unity subordinate to $\{Z_{\iota} : \iota \in I\}$.

Comment: Then $$\psi = \sum_{\{\iota : Z_{\iota} \cap B \neq \varnothing\}} \varphi_{\iota}$$ is a smooth function (since it's a locally finite sum of smooth functions) with $\psi\lvert_A \equiv 0$ and $\psi\lvert_B \equiv 1$. I'm not quite sure what one needs for the infinite-dimensional case. It is sufficient that the space be separable (hence second countable), and the norm be smooth (except at $0$). So for example on separable Hilbert spaces, things work. I think the separability is necessary and the condition on the norm isn't, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Rubertos Ah, I see you edited your comment to say that you don't know about smooth partitions of unity while I typed. No big deal. Are you familiar with convolutions?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I actually used convolution to prove the compact-open version of $C^\infty$ Urysohn lemma.

Comment: @Rubertos Good. Then just note that in the construction of the partition of unity on $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can assume that the functions with compact support you start with are in fact smooth. All further constructions preserve smoothness (since the family of supports is locally finite), and thus you end up with a smooth partition of unity. Can you see how that works?

Comment: I have a meal appointment right now so as soon as I come back I will try! Thank you so much