# A C-infinity Urysohn Type Result

Tags: real-analysis

We work in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $K$ be a compact set. Let $C$ be a closed set. Suppose there exists an open set $U$ such that $K \cap U \neq \emptyset$ and $K \cap U \subseteq K \cap C$. How can I choose a non-negative $C^{\infty}$ function $f$ such $f>0$ on $K \cap U$ and $f=0$ on $U^c$?

I know the usual $C^{\infty}$ Urysohn lemma (if $K'$ compact and $U'$ open and $K' \subseteq U'$, then there is a non-negative $C^{\infty}$ $f$ such that $f=1$ on $K'$ and $\text{supp}(f) \subseteq U'$). But I can't see how to apply it here.

I also read this question, since it seemed relevant, but I couldn't see how to use it: [An stronger form of the existence of a smooth Urysohn function on $\mathbb R^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385079/an-stronger-form-of-the-existence-of-a-smooth-urysohn-function-on-mathbb-rn)